# Javascript: Split with more than one parameters

Tags: javascript, split

Is there a function in Java Script that divide a string with several arguments?

```
var string = "This is a test text, again, this is a testing text";
```

For example, I can split with `,` by saying `string.split(',');` and I will have:

```
var string = ["This is a test text", "again", "this is a testing text"];
```

Now, I want to split it with several parameters, so string now would be

```
var string = ["test text", "testing text"]
```

I'm looking for a function that extract all the parts that start with `test` and end with `text`.

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) some text before splitting?

Comment: please clarify your question - it's not clear what you really want to achieve.

Comment: `/test(.+)text/g`?

Comment: If people are asking you to clarify, then it, obviously, was not clear to them. Saying "think that everything is clarified enough" comes off as arrogant. Something more along the lines of "I'm sorry what I posted did not communicate clearly.  I'm not sure how I could clarify it for you. What does not appear to be clear?" would probably result in better communication.

Comment: sure, I apologize, but as I said I want to have to be splitted by 'test' start and 'text' end.

Comment: anyway, let me know what you want to be clarified if something is not clear

Comment: @MikeC, thanks for the regex, but this would look across all the text, so it would end with `test text` only. So if `var string = "tester text, test text, testing text"`, it would end with `"tester text"`, `tester` being the first word in the string, and `text` being the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood what you want, but here is a function I wrote in 2 minutes. With the following scenario

```
var string = "This is a test text, again, this is a testing text";

function customSplit(str_to_split, start_string, end_string) {
    var res = [];
    var start_index, end_index;

    for (i = 0; i <= str_to_split.length; i++) {
        start_index = str_to_split.toLowerCase().indexOf(start_string.toLowerCase(), i);
        if (i == start_index) {
            end_index = str_to_split.toLowerCase().indexOf(end_string.toLowerCase(), i);
            if (end_index >= 0) {
                res.push(str_to_split.substring(start_index, end_index + end_string.length));
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}

console.log(customSplit(string, "test", "text"));
```

it will output `["test text", "testing text"]`.

Let me know if it helps you.

**EDIT**

Corrected a wrong behave with a particular string. Please remind that I wrote it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: This helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Please check the updated answer, as the function had a wrong behaviour with a particular string, and please bear in mind that it's just a quick example. Adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```js
var str = "This is a test text, again, this is a testing text";
console.log(str.match(/test.+?text/g));
```